# Geometry Nodes: How to transfer normals from Icosphere to instanced planes (nice cartoony leaves in a tree)

Tags: geometry-nodes

I thought this was simple but can't figure out how it's done.

So how to do the same in Geometry Nodes than on the bush on the right? (Which is applied geometry with a NormalEdit modifier, that transfers the normals from the wireframe-icosphere to the leaves)

So how to get to the same result than on the right?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you can see the modified part of your node setup.

[image: node setup]

We store the desired normals in a named attribute called *my_normal*. You could choose nearly any other name here, as well. The normals have to be stored for the ico sphere and the leaves as well. For the ico sphere we store the original normals. For the leaves, we grab the normal of the nearest point of the ico sphere.

Then in the material, we reference this attribute:

[image: material]

And here is, how it looks like.

[image: result]

[image]

Comment: Wohoo! Thank you :)

Comment: You are welcome :-)